# AppCode not showing warnings

Tags: swift, xcode, appcode

I am using AppCode 2022.1.2 and I have Xcode version 13.3 and issue is that in AppCode I can not see warnings as in Xcode. Please refer on screenshots below. Is there any set up for AppCode that will enable showing this warnings? Thanks.

Appcode:
[image: Appcode]

Xcode:
[image: Xcode]

Comment: I don't see this initializer. Is it an extension you wrote? Is it a failable initializer?